How to solve equations with nested radicals? Specifically, find $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ if $\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}+\sqrt[3]{n-\sqrt{n^2+8}}=8$
I've tried some basic approaches like cubing both sides or multiplying by a conjugate, but I am getting nowhere and it's only getting uglier. I used to run a school's club for MATHCOUNTS and this reminds me of some of those competition problems where there's a really slick trick to solve them easily, but if you don't know the trick, it's quite difficult. That's kinda where my head is right now, but I obviously could have missed some easy technique. Any advice on how to get started in the right direction would be great

You can always brute force it by moving a cube root to one side and cubing. You say you tried this... What failed?

Here is another method: Change one two two.
Let $x=\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}},y=\sqrt[3]{n-\sqrt{n^2+8}}$. So we have $x+y=8$, and also $xy=\sqrt[3]{(n+\sqrt{n^2+8})(n-\sqrt{n^2+8})}=\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$. Therefore, you have
$$n=\frac{x^3+y^3}{2}=\frac{x+y}{2}(x^2+y^2-xy)=\frac{x+y}{2}((x+y)^2-3xy)=4\cdot (64+2\cdot 3)=280.$$

Sorry, another method found.
You just cube both sides, as you said. Believe me, not that ugly.
That is,
$$\left(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}+\sqrt[3]{n-\sqrt{n^2+8}}\right)^3=512$$
Expand, you have
$$(n+\sqrt{n^2+8})+(n-\sqrt{n^2+8})+3\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}\sqrt[3]{n-\sqrt{n^2+8}}\left(\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}+\sqrt[3]{n-\sqrt{n^2+8}}\right)=512$$
Using $\sqrt[3]{(n-\sqrt{n^2+8})(n+\sqrt{n^2+8})}=-2$, and substitute again $\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}+\sqrt[3]{n-\sqrt{n^2+8}}=8$, we have
$$2n+3\cdot (-2)\cdot 8=512$$
Then $n=280$.

Ah, yeah I did try to cube it but I see now I just made a simple mistake which made it look much uglier lol. Thank you!

Let $x=\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}$
Since $\sqrt[3]{n-\sqrt{n^2+8}}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}} $ then we have
$x-\frac{2}{x}=8$ then $x=4+3\sqrt{2}$
and we get $n=280$

Here is Cardano's formula for solving a depressed cubic, a cubic equation of the form $t^3+pt+q=0$:
$$t=\sqrt[3]{-\frac q2+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac q2-\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}}}$$
Hmm. Looks a lot like your equation. In fact, with $p=6$ and $q=-2n$, this is your equation.
Therefore, we find that $8$ is a root of the polynomial $t^3+6t-2n=0$.
You can now just divide by $(t-8)$ to obtain $$t^2+8t+70+\frac{560-2n}{t-8}=0$$
Since $t=8$ is a root, the remainder must be zero: $560-2n=0$. Finally, $n=280$.

I have a strong feeling that the intended trick is to know that
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$$
so in particular with $x = \sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}$, $y = \sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2-8}}$, and $z = -8$ we have $x+y+z = 0$ so
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz = 0 $$
$$2n-512+24\sqrt[3]{(n+\sqrt{n^2+8})(n-\sqrt{n^2+8})} = 0 $$
$$2n-512-48 = 0 $$
$$n = 280$$
